# Is there a way to retrieve indices of particular values using Pycuda?

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, pycuda

I have a 3D numpy array of size 1000x1000x1000. I am looking for the indices of the values 1 in the entire array. The np.nonzero(array) is very slow for larger dataset as mine. I was wondering if there is a way to do it via pycuda. Or is there some other more efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used PyCuda before, but since I found a [good example on how to use thrust in PyCuda](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/ThrustInterop), I came up with the following solution.

Internally, it uses `thrust::counting_iterator` and `thrust::copy_if` to find the indices of the elements which are equal to `1`.

While this may be faster, there is a serious flaw in your whole problem:
You have an array with 1 billion (1000000000) elements, which needs 4 GB memory when using 32bit integers.
You will need another output array which is 4 GB as well.
Even if your GPU has that much RAM, the input data needs to be copied to the GPU, which will take some time.

If your array consists of mainly zero entries, you might be better off with using a [sparse matrix format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix) and only store non-zero entries.
This will save memory and you do not have to search for non-zero entries at all.

**find_indices_thrust.py**

```
import pycuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import numpy as np

from codepy.cgen import *
from codepy.bpl import BoostPythonModule
from codepy.cuda import CudaModule

#Make a host_module, compiled for CPU
host_mod = BoostPythonModule()

#Make a device module, compiled with NVCC
nvcc_mod = CudaModule(host_mod)

#Describe device module code
#NVCC includes
nvcc_includes = [
    'thrust/copy.h',
    'thrust/device_vector.h',
    'thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h',
    'thrust/functional.h',
    'cuda.h',
    'stdint.h'
    ]
#Add includes to module
nvcc_mod.add_to_preamble([Include(x) for x in nvcc_includes])

#NVCC function
nvcc_function = FunctionBody(
    FunctionDeclaration(Value('void', 'find_indices'),
                        [Value('CUdeviceptr', 'input_ptr'),
                        Value('uint32_t', 'input_length'),
                        Value('CUdeviceptr', 'output_ptr'),
                        Value('uint32_t*', 'output_length')]),
    Block([Statement('thrust::device_ptr<uint32_t> thrust_input_ptr((uint32_t*)input_ptr)'),
          Statement('thrust::device_ptr<uint32_t> thrust_output_ptr((uint32_t*)output_ptr)'),
          Statement('using namespace thrust::placeholders'),
          Statement('*output_length = thrust::copy_if(thrust::counting_iterator<uint32_t>(0), thrust::counting_iterator<uint32_t>(input_length), thrust_input_ptr, thrust_output_ptr, _1==1)-thrust_output_ptr')]))

#Add declaration to nvcc_mod
#Adds declaration to host_mod as well
nvcc_mod.add_function(nvcc_function)

host_includes = [
    'boost/python/extract.hpp',
    ]
#Add host includes to module
host_mod.add_to_preamble([Include(x) for x in host_includes])

host_namespaces = [
    'using namespace boost::python',
    ]

#Add BPL using statement
host_mod.add_to_preamble([Statement(x) for x in host_namespaces])


host_statements = [
    #Extract information from PyCUDA GPUArray
    #Get length
    'tuple shape = extract<tuple>(gpu_input_array.attr("shape"))',
    'int input_length = extract<int>(shape[0])',
    #Get input data pointer
    'CUdeviceptr input_ptr = extract<CUdeviceptr>(gpu_input_array.attr("ptr"))',
    #Get output data pointer
    'CUdeviceptr output_ptr = extract<CUdeviceptr>(gpu_output_array.attr("ptr"))',
    #Call Thrust routine, compiled into the CudaModule
    'uint32_t output_size',
    'find_indices(input_ptr, input_length, output_ptr, &output_size)',
    #Return result
    'return output_size',
    ]

host_mod.add_function(
    FunctionBody(
        FunctionDeclaration(Value('int', 'host_entry'),
                            [Value('object', 'gpu_input_array'),Value('object', 'gpu_output_array')]),
        Block([Statement(x) for x in host_statements])))

#Print out generated code, to see what we're actually compiling
print("---------------------- Host code ----------------------")
print(host_mod.generate())
print("--------------------- Device code ---------------------")
print(nvcc_mod.generate())
print("-------------------------------------------------------")



#Compile modules
import codepy.jit, codepy.toolchain
gcc_toolchain = codepy.toolchain.guess_toolchain()
nvcc_toolchain = codepy.toolchain.guess_nvcc_toolchain()

module = nvcc_mod.compile(gcc_toolchain, nvcc_toolchain, debug=True)



length = 100
input_array = np.array(np.random.rand(length)*5, dtype=np.uint32)
output_array = np.zeros(length, dtype=np.uint32)

print("---------------------- INPUT -----------------------")
print(input_array)
gpu_input_array = gpuarray.to_gpu(input_array)
gpu_output_array = gpuarray.to_gpu(output_array)

# call GPU function
output_size = module.host_entry(gpu_input_array, gpu_output_array)
print("----------------------- OUTPUT ------------------------")
print gpu_output_array[:output_size]
print("-------------------------------------------------------")
```

---

**generated code**

```
---------------------- Host code ----------------------
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <cuda.h>
void find_indices(CUdeviceptr input_ptr, uint32_t input_length, CUdeviceptr output_ptr, uint32_t* output_length);
#include <boost/python/extract.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

namespace private_namespace_6f5e74fc4bebe20d5478de66e2226656
{
  int host_entry(object gpu_input_array, object gpu_output_array)
  {
    tuple shape = extract<tuple>(gpu_input_array.attr("shape"));
    int input_length = extract<int>(shape[0]);
    CUdeviceptr input_ptr = extract<CUdeviceptr>(gpu_input_array.attr("ptr"));
    CUdeviceptr output_ptr = extract<CUdeviceptr>(gpu_output_array.attr("ptr"));
    uint32_t output_size;
    find_indices(input_ptr, input_length, output_ptr, &output_size);
    return output_size;
  }
}

using namespace private_namespace_6f5e74fc4bebe20d5478de66e2226656;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module)
{
  boost::python::def("host_entry", &host_entry);
}
--------------------- Device code ---------------------
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void find_indices(CUdeviceptr input_ptr, uint32_t input_length, CUdeviceptr output_ptr, uint32_t* output_length)
{
  thrust::device_ptr<uint32_t> thrust_input_ptr((uint32_t*)input_ptr);
  thrust::device_ptr<uint32_t> thrust_output_ptr((uint32_t*)output_ptr);
  using namespace thrust::placeholders;
  *output_length = thrust::copy_if(thrust::counting_iterator<uint32_t>(0), thrust::counting_iterator<uint32_t>(input_length), thrust_input_ptr, thrust_output_ptr, _1==1)-thrust_output_ptr;
}
-------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**demo output**

```
---------------------- INPUT -----------------------
[1 2 3 0 3 3 1 2 1 2 0 4 4 3 2 0 4 2 3 0 2 3 1 4 3 4 3 4 3 2 4 3 2 4 2 0 3
0 3 4 3 0 0 4 4 2 0 3 3 1 3 4 2 0 0 4 0 4 3 2 3 2 1 1 4 3 0 4 3 1 1 1 3 2
0 0 3 4 3 3 4 2 2 3 4 1 1 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 0 2 4 3 2 0]
----------------------- OUTPUT ------------------------
[ 0  6  8 22 49 62 63 69 70 71 85 86]
-------------------------------------------------------
```